# error "Shadow pid 3161 for job 14.0 exited with status 4" (condor jobs are not running..)

Tags: condor

I'm running job on a condor cluster, its showring erro..

"Shadow pid 3161 for job 14.0 exited with status 4"

#condor_q -analyze 14

Last successful match: Mon Jul 18 12:40:34 2022

014.000:  Run analysis summary ignoring user priority.  Of 192 machines,

```
  0 are rejected by your job's requirements
  0 reject your job because of their own requirements
  0 match and are already running your jobs
  0 match but are serving other users
192 are able to run your job
```

Please help me to resolve the issue..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This means there was some unexpected error when running the condor_shadow.  This process keeps a log in the file named ShadowLog, which, depending on your installation, is often in the directory /var/log/condor.  Can you find the specific error in that file?

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to resolve the issue but failed, finally  I've upgraded the version 8 to 9.1,its working now.